# Is there any way we can access the `shared with me` files in graph API Microsoft using application permission?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way we can access the `shared with me` files in graph API Microsoft using `application permission` as it is working fine with the delegated permission but I want it using application permission.
@ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_sharedwithme?view=odsp-graph-online. I tried this approach

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{User-Principal-Name}/drive/sharedWithMe
```

But getting a response with the values field empty.
[Response I am getting after running this request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY7Vt.png)

Any Help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not currently supported but the team is investigating the work needed to add support.