# Issue accessing a list from another user/site(not owned by me, but shared with me, can access via web) using Microsoft Graph 1.0?

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I've checked the issue : [Is there any way we can access the `shared with me` files in graph API Microsoft using application permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344684/is-there-any-way-we-can-access-the-shared-with-me-files-in-graph-api-microsoft) as it's fairly close to my issue but not exacly, so raising a new issue.

I have a list shared with me by another member of my organisation that I can open and access though browser.

let's say the URL is : https://365.sharepoint.com/teams/IC/Lists/Cult%20Tracker/Allitemsg.aspx#InplviewHash7c06d6bd-0344-43fd-8057-ffc7deeec3f7=ShowInGrid%3DTrue

Now I'm trying to pull this data via python and do some analytics on it.
So, I tried "sharepoint" & "Office365-REST-Python-Client" packages but both didn't work and kept throwing 403.

The codes I have tried are :

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener

server_url = "https://<host>365.sharepoint.com/"
site_url = server_url + "teams/IC"

opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "slaik@<host>.com", "Abcdefgh")
# also tried domain/slaik as userid

site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)

for sp_list in site.lists:
    print(sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title'])
```

The error i got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/slaik/OneDrive - <host>/Migrated from My PC/Documents/Sandeep/Scripts/Python/PycharmProjects/IC_KPI_Report/sharepoint_conect.py", line 10, in <module>
    for sp_list in site.lists:
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\sharepoint\lists\__init__.py", line 80, in __iter__
    return iter(self.all_lists)
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\sharepoint\lists\__init__.py", line 36, in all_lists
    result = self.opener.post_soap(LIST_WEBSERVICE, xml)
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\sharepoint\site.py", line 32, in post_soap
    response = self.opener.open(request, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "c:\users\slaik\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\users\slaik\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\users\slaik\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\users\slaik\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\slaik\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

and

```
import json

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

url = "https://<host>365.sharepoint.com/teams/IC"
username = "slaik@<host>.com" #also tried domain/slaik as userid
password = "Abcdefgh"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  request = ClientRequest(ctx_auth)
  options = RequestOptions("{0}/_api/web/".format(url))
  options.set_header('Accept', 'application/json')
  options.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  data = request.execute_request_direct(options)
  s = json.loads(data.content)
  web_title = s['Title']
  print("Web title: " + web_title)
else:
  print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

the error i got:

```
An error occurred while retrieving token: AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/slaik/OneDrive - <host>/Migrated from My PC/Documents/Sandeep/Scripts/Python/PycharmProjects/IC_KPI_Report/sharepoint_conect.py", line 30, in <module>
    data = request.execute_request_direct(options)
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 104, in execute_request_direct
    self.context.authenticate_request(request_options)
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py", line 35, in authenticate_request
    request_options.set_header('Cookie', self.provider.get_authentication_cookie())
  File "C:\Users\slaik\OneDrive - <host>\Migrated from My PC\Documents\Sandeep\Scripts\Python\PycharmProjects\IC_KPI_Report\venv\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 69, in get_authentication_cookie
    return 'FedAuth=' + self.FedAuth + '; rtFa=' + self.rtFa
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

In one answer in stack overflow I got to know that it doesn't work that way anymore and I should use Microsoft graph api.

So, I logged into the api console and provided it Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All among other permissions.

So, now if I try this : Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=IC

I'm getting a response 200:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2017-05-26T14:04:29Z",
            "id": "<host>365.sharepoint.com,fec353b1-bd1a-4569-acd9-6421737b81d6,5b449746-eaae-4941-b044-ef9703a6b2ee",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T08:00:00Z",
            "name": "IC",
            "webUrl": "https://<host>365.sharepoint.com/teams/IC",
            "displayName": "IC Division - MRC",
            "root": {},
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "<host>365.sharepoint.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I try this :Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/IC/lists

or this : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/IC/lists/Cult%20Tracker

I get an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid hostname for this tenancy",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ab43af0a-6be0-4a40-91ab-5a4ff52bc261",
            "date": "2019-10-17T14:05:52"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm referring to the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0
and not sure what am I missing.

Thanks for reading through this long description and any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the site id [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request)

```
GET /sites/{site-id}
```

In other words, your URI should be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/host>365.sharepoint.com,fec353b1-bd1a-4569-acd9-6421737b81d6,5b449746-eaae-4941-b044-ef9703a6b2ee/lists
```

Comment: I received a sharepoint share link and I only need to enter a password to access.
How do I access this data via API? It is possible? Access data from a shared link?